# Publify: how to write markdown in Publify?

Tags: markdown, publify

I want to use [Publify](https://github.com/fdv/publify) to create a new blog.

*Publify supports various editors (visual, plain HTML, Markdown, Textile)*

It's great, but I don't know how to create a new article with Markdown systax.

I used `<code>`, `<pre>`, `{{#markdown}}`, `<publify:code lang="Markdown">`, `<publify:code lang="markdown">`, but doesn't work.

How to write markdown in Publify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under your user profile (Logged in as... -> Profile) choose the "Markdown" option for the "Article filters" in the Profile Settings section.

After setting that option, you'll be able to use markdown in the article editor.